Speech Recognition Issue: Unable to Process Audio Buffer from Client-Side Streaming in Python Backend
I'm encountering an issue with speech recognition when trying to process audio streamed from a client to a Python backend. Here's a breakdown of the process:
Client-Side (JavaScript):
audioRecorder.ondataavailable = function(event) {
    if (event.data && event.data.size > 0) {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function() {
            const buffer = reader.result;
            const chunkSize = 1024 * 32;
            for (let i = 0; i < buffer.byteLength; i += chunkSize) {
                const chunk = buffer.slice(i, i + chunkSize);
                const uint8Array = new Uint8Array(chunk);
                ws.send(JSON.stringify({ type: 'AUDIO_FRAME', data: Array.from(uint8Array) }));
            }
        };
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(event.data);
    }
}

Server-Side (Python):
elif data['type'] == 'AUDIO_FRAME':
    audio_bytes = bytes(data['data'])
    audio_file.write(audio_bytes)
    recognize_speech(audio_bytes)

Speech Recognition Function (Python):
import speech_recognition as sr

sample_rate = 48000
sample_width = 2
chunk_duration = 1

audio_buffer = b''
recognizer = sr.Recognizer()

def recognize_speech(audio_data):
    global audio_buffer
    audio_buffer += audio_data
    buffer_size = sample_rate * sample_width * chunk_duration

    if len(audio_buffer) >= buffer_size:
        try:
            chunk_bytes = audio_buffer[:buffer_size]
            audio_buffer = audio_buffer[buffer_size:]
            audio = sr.AudioData(chunk_bytes, sample_rate, sample_width)
            text = recognizer.recognize_google(audio)
            print("Recognized:", text)
        except sr.UnknownValueError:
            print("Could not understand audio")
        except sr.RequestError as e:
            print(f"Request error from Google Speech Recognition service: {e}")

However, despite successful audio streaming and storage on the server, the speech recognition consistently returns an UnknownValueError. Interestingly, when I tested the speech recognition with live microphone input in a Jupyter notebook, it worked flawlessly.
I'd appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue and successfully transcribe the streamed audio.
I attempted to store the audio file on the server from the streaming chunks. While I could play the stored audio and hear it clearly. However, there is not much clarity when I was storing chunks in recognize_speech function.
Let me know if you need anymore details.
Thank you!
